# how to configure samba to be visible in another subnet

Tags: networking, samba

I have a subnet 192.168.1.0/24 and in it I vave a smbd/nmbd server
The samba server is for example: 192.168.1.25
the gateway/router here is 192.168.1.1

in this subnet there is a cascading router 192.168.1.100 that has his own subnet 192.168.2.0/24, in this second subnet there are some windows clients who must access the samba shares at 192.168.1.25

how to configure this?

Comment: How does this relate to Ubuntu? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please edit your question and add this information.

Comment: A possible duplicate of [Access ip on another subnet](https://superuser.com/questions/1305960/access-ip-on-another-subnet) in Superuser. This is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @user68186 Welcome to SE, my question is the oposite of the cited question. I want to go from client2 to client1 in his diagram.

Comment: Try setting up port forwarding rules in your cascading router (192.168.1.100) so that the smb server can talk to the client in the 192.168.2.x subnet. This should work for one smb  client.